# In Google Sheets, how can you find the mode of non-numerical data?

Tags: function, math, google-sheets, formulas

If I want to find the mode of A2:A10, but my values are something like:

```
Foo
Foo
Bar
Foo
Baz
Bar
Foo
Bar
Foo
```

, what can I do?

The `=MODE()` function only takes numerical data, so is there a way to find the most frequent of these values? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a MATCH on a MAX(COUNTIF(...)) to a COUNTIF and pass the row position back to an INDEX.

```
=index(A2:A10, match(max(countif(A2:A10, A2:A10)), countif(A2:A10, A2:A10), 0))
```

In the case of a tie in frequency, the first in the list that matches the maximum frequency rate will be returned.

[image: google-sheets_max_text_frequency]

Comment: Just wondering, why does this work? (BTW, it worked like a charm)

Comment: The [google-sheets] formula is processed like an Excel array formula. If you put it into an Excel worksheet with CSE you canSelect B2 and use the [Evaluate Formula](https://goo.gl/Vl25be) command. Repeat if necessary until you understand it. Keep the ranges small or the results from the cyclic processing can get confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have Microsoft Excel. (I use OS X)

Comment: This doesn't work when you have more than one modes.

Comment: what happen when there is multiple text value with same count..multiple modes?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(index($A$1:$A$10, mode(match($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,0))))
```

`MATCH` function will give you the position of each first entry, which is a numerical value and can be used inside `MODE` function, then we can use `INDEX` function to extract the value from this list.